# Can't retrieve data from Access DB query to my VB program

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, vba

So this is my code so far...
I have 2 DateTimePickers in which the user selects the first day of the week and the last day of the week, once selected these two I want to calculate the hours worked on each day and add them so I can display the amount of hours worked of the interval of days selected.

My Work table contains an idEmployee, Date, ArrivalTime, DepartureTime, and a calculated column(Hrs_worked) that displays the amount of hours worked on that day.

When I run the program a message box pops an shows this "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid" or "Mismatch of data in the expression of criteria"
Do I need to change the datetimepickers values to string values?

Im working on Visual Basic Express 2010 with an Access Database

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dataFile As String = "E:\SIDB.accdb"
    Dim connString As String = provider & dataFile
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

    Dim qHrsWorked As String = "SELECT SUM(Hrs_worked) FROM Work WHERE IdEmployee = " & idEmptxt.Text & " AND Date >= " & firstDayDTP.Value & " AND Date <= " & lastDayDTP.Value & ""

    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(qHrsWorked, myConnection)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read
            hrsWorkedtxt.Text = reader.Item(0)

        End While
        reader.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: The data mismatch is because you are not using SQL parameters.  Period.  The DbNull conversion error may result when no records match the query passed, which may be malformed due to not using SQL Parameters.  Also your app is leaking resources.  And use SQL Parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you must use a formatted string expression for the date values:

```
Dim qHrsWorked As String = "SELECT SUM(Hrs_worked) FROM Work WHERE IdEmployee = " & idEmptxt.Text & " AND Date >= #" & firstDayDTP.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "# AND Date <= #" & lastDayDTP.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Thank you very very much

Answer (score 1):

I haven't written Access queries in years and do not have it to try now, but if I remember correctly DateTime values in the query need to be surrounded with hash marks (#).

```
Dim qHrsWorked As String = _
    "SELECT SUM(Hrs_worked) FROM Work WHERE IdEmployee = " & idEmptxt.Text & _
    " AND Date >= #" & firstDayDTP.Value & "# AND Date <= #" & LastDayDTP.Value & "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you use Textbox.Text for your datepickers. You can only use that property when the control has focus. Try replacing those with .Value ?

Comment: I changed to .Value and now the error message shows this "Syntax error (missing operator) in the expression 'IdEmployee =  1 AND Date >= 02/07/2016 05:06:37 pm AND Date >= 08/07/2016 05:06:37 pm'. "