# vb.net : DateTimePicker switches formats when queried

Tags: vb.net, date, datepicker

So my DateTimePicker's format on Visual Basic 2010 is `dd/MM/yyyy` but whenever I query the date it queries itself in this format `MM/dd/yyyy`

Example:
I have 3 registers on my database which are...

02/07/2016  (format is dd/mm/yyyy)

03/07/2016

04/07/2016

If in my datetimepicker I select 02/07/2016 and 05/07/2016 it reads it as 07/02/2016 and 07/05/2016
Why does this happen?

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dataFile As String = "E:\Serna Impresos 2016\Serna Impresos 2016\Serna Impresos 2016\bin\Debug\SIDB.accdb"
    Dim connString As String = provider & dataFile
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand


    Dim qHrsTrab As String = "SELECT SUM(Horas_trabajadas) FROM Trabaja WHERE IdEmpleado = " & IdEmptxt.Text & " AND Fecha >= #" & consultaIniDTP.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "# AND Fecha <= #" & ConsultaFinDTP.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "#"

    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(qHrsTrab, myConnection)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read
            hrsTrabajadastxt.Text = reader.Item(0)

        End While
        reader.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        hrsTrabajadastxt.Text = 0
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same *yyyy-mm-dd* formatting as showed in your last question:

[Can't retrieve data from Access DB query to my VB program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362211/cant-retrieve-data-from-access-db-query-to-my-vb-program/38369592#38369592)